# how to control the width of ggpattern's fill pattern

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to decrease the width of `ggpattern`'s fill pattern, making it looks like a black oblique line. However, my script did not work.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

ggplot(sf_poly) + 
    geom_sf_pattern(pattern_fill = "transparent", fill = "transparent", 
        # pattern = 0,
        pattern_size = 0.2,
        pattern_type = 3,
        color = "transparent",
        size = 0.2)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [packages "stripe" vignette](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/patterns-stripes.html) you can use the `pattern_density` aesthetic to control the area the pattern fills i.e. in this case a lower `pattern_density` value will decrease the width of the stripes.  Alternatively decreasing `pattern_spacing` will increase the number of stripes which would also reduce the stripe width for a fixed `pattern_density` value (more stripes filling a given area means each stripe must be smaller).